# Making a string that adapts itself to the text inside it

Tags: vb.net, string, math, equation

I'm making a program to solve second grade equations (e.g. 2x²+2x+2) and I was trying to have the user input the whole equation in a single text box.  The computer then stores what has been typed into the text box in a string, and then it parses the string to find the coefficents.  For an equation like 2x²+2x+2, the coeficients are 2, 2 and 2 and they are stored in the string at locations 0, 4 and 7.  The big problem is, what if it's a bigger equation like 32x²+32x+45 or 123x²+45x+6?  My logic won't work in that case.  Does anyone know how to do it?

Here's my code that only works for the small equations:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim i1 As Double
    Dim i2 As Double
    Dim i3 As Double
    Dim delta As Double
    Dim x1 As Double
    Dim x2 As Double
    Dim leters As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        i1 = T1.Text
        i2 = T2.Text
        i3 = T3.Text
        delta = (i2 * i2) - 4 * (i1 * i3)
        If (delta < 0) Then
            Ld.Text = delta
            L1.Text = "Impossível"
            L2.Text = "Impossível"
        Else
            x1 = (-i2 + Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * i1)
            x2 = (-i2 - Math.Sqrt(delta)) / (2 * i1)
            Ld.Text = delta
            L1.Text = x1
            L2.Text = x2
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
        GroupBox1.Text = "Equação"
        GroupBox1.Width = 200
        GroupBox1.Height = 58
        T1.Width = 188
        T3.Hide()
        T2.Hide()
        Label1.Hide()
        Button1.Hide()
        Button2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
        GroupBox1.Text = "Coeficientes"
        GroupBox1.Width = 200
        GroupBox1.Height = 143
        T1.Width = 119
        T3.Show()
        T2.Show()
        Label1.Show()
        Button1.Show()
        Button2.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        leters = T1.Text
        leters.ToString()
    End Sub    
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use RegEx to parse the string, which would be nice because you could change the RegEx expression as a setting without rebuilding your assembly.  However, if the equation string format is always going to be the same, as appears to be the case here (because the rest of the code would fail if it weren't), then you could simply use `String.Split` to parse the string.  For instance:

```
Dim equation As String = "32x²+32x+45"
Dim parts() As String = equation.Split(New Char() {"+"c, "x"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim coefficient1 As Integer = Integer.Parse(parts(0))
Dim coefficient2 As Integer = Integer.Parse(parts(2))
Dim coefficient3 As Integer = Integer.Parse(parts(3))
```